# how to checkout old version from GIT

Tags: git

we have a remote git repository, and a development branch.

i'd like to "fork" a particualr directory for (a-la code freeze).

for example,

```
|
+ -dir1
   |
   + -dir2
   |
   + -dir3
```

i need to create a copy dir2, (e.g. as "dir2_frozen") so it contains new folder with files from a specific date.

the "dir2_frozen" dir will not commit any changes.

```
|
+ -dir1
   |
   +--dir2
   |
   +==dir2_frozen
   |
   + -dir3
```

i'd rather not use branches in the original directory, because i need both versions active and running.

i'd rather not fork the whole repository (it's HUGE)

how can i do that?

Comment: as you may see, i'm new to git

Comment: Creating a branch does not *deactivate* or *stop* anything. Did you try to create one?

Comment: i created a new branch. how can the programs be run and libraries be used from branch2 (current) while i'm actively running and importing libraries on branch2_frozen ? is it some kind of a magic?

Comment: Are you developing on the production system?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going into squashing bugs mode for release, then creating a branch is exactly what you want to do.

If you want to refer to an exact point in time in your code base, create a tag. You will do this when you actually release, for instance.